# ERROR ao iniciar o projeto java com tomcat

Tags: java, tomcat

Coloquei o war do projeto na pasta webapp mas a aplicação nao aparece no navegador dá esse erro:

```
SEVERE: Error deploying web application archive webrun.war
java.lang.UnsupportedClassVersionError: Bad version number in .class file(unable to load class wfr.web.WebrunContextListener)


No navegador:
```

HTTP Status 503 - This application is not currently available

type Status report

message This application is not currently available

description The requested service is not currently available.
Apache Tomcat/6.0.37

Comment: Resolvi o problema. Era a versao do tomcat

Comment: jdk1.6 funfa no tomcat 7

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Conform já mencionado em comentários, o erro é sim pela tentativa de carregar uma classe compilada com uma versão diferente do Java.

Por exemplo, as classes do WAR foram compiladas com Java 7 e o Tomcat executa no Java 6. Ora, Java 6 não consegue entender classes da versão 7, embora o contrário aconteça.

Veja a [documentação](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/UnsupportedClassVersionError.html).

A solução, neste caso, pode ser:

- Compilar as classes com a mesma versão onde elas serão executadas
- Ou executar com a mesma versão que elas foram compiladas

Se entendi bem, a solução do AP foi a do segundo item.

Além disso, diferente do que foi mencionado, arquivos WAR e correlatos não são agnósticos em relação à versão do Java. É verdade que eles são arquivos ZIP, mas em 99.9% dos casos eles possuem classes compiladas dentro usando um JDK específico.

Este não é um problema raro.

A forma de se certificar é extrair o WAR e olhar na pasta `WEB-INF/classes` a versão das classes. Isso pode ser feito com o comando `javap`, por exemplo:

```
javap -verbose MinhaClasse
```